# #define on a specific translation unit from another

Tags: c++

I would like to ask if it's possible to do this 
If it is, how can it be done? 
I want to do this because I want to "update" a class but I don't have access to edit that class
(class B simply adds a variable to class A)

A.h

```
#pragma once
class A
{
public:
int x;
A();
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
A::A():x(0){}
```

update_to_A.h

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"
class B: public A
{
public:
int y;
B();
};
```

update_to_A.cpp

```
#include "update_to_A.h"
B::B():y(1){}
```

And the written in main would be like this

main.cpp (written like this)

```
#include "A.h"
#include "update_to_A.h"
int main()
{
A object; //variables: x (supposed to be x, y) 
};
```

But I want it to act like this

main.cpp (act like this)

```
#include "A.h"
#include "update_to_A.h"
int main()
{
B object; //variables: x, y
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea for many reasons. In order of increasing importance:

- It is confusing to read. Why does `A` suddenly mean `B`?
- It most likely breaks single responsibility. `A` is supposed to do a specific thing, so wanting it to suddenly be a `B` is probably making it do things that it's not originally supposed to.
- If other code also uses `A` (the old one) and wants to interact with your code, it wouldn't know about this change in meaning, which will quickly lead to problems. For example, each `B` needs more space than an `A`, so you cannot put them into the same array.
- It is not possible to do this in C++ without resorting to **extremely ugly and dangerous** tricks. You can `#define A B` in `update_to_A.h` and work from there, but I must stress that **this is the wrong way**. You are headed for pain and suffering if you try that.

Let me be abundantly clear: Any way in which you achieve what you described in the question will be a dirty hack. It's not maintainable, very brittle and will most likely cause unsolveable issues before it does whatever you wanted to really achieve.

If you want to have a `B` in your `main`, why not use `B`? Why abuse `A` like that?

Comment: The class B will be like class A (these are Simplified names to keep things simple) but it only adds a variable. If someone wants to use the original class A, then they just don't include the update_to_A.h, and things will like how A is supposed to be.

Comment: @ALTR even so, your program is almost guaranteed to crash when you include some headers in different orders in different places

Comment: I just want to add a variable in A (and a function to process the new variable), but you can't edit a class from somewhere outside the class (you can only define things from within the curly braces of the class), so I resulted to this (because I don't have editing access to the original class)

Comment: But why do you need the new class to also be called `A`? If you want _existing_ code (that you won't change) to respect this change, it almost surely won't work. If it's only for your own code... Just write `B` instead of `A`?